# Cancel a hook subscription

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm using [React Native Hook's useKeyboard()](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-hooks#usekeyboard) hook to change a `state` when the keyboard opens, bundled in a `useEffect()` as such:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useKeyboard } from "react-native-hooks";

import { Container, Logo, Input } from "../components/UI";

const Sample = () => {
  const [shouldDisplay, setDisplay] = useState(true);

  const { isKeyboardShow } = useKeyboard();
  // This is where it breaks
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isKeyboardShow !== undefined) {
      setDisplay(!isKeyboardShow); // Hide Logo when keyboard is shown
    }
    // I should return a cleanup() function but what to put in it?
  }, [isKeyboardShow]);

  return (
    <Container>
      {shouldDisplay && <Logo />}
      <Input />
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Sample;
```

But when I navigate to another `view` (using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)), if the keyboard opens, then I get an error

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I'm sure this piece of code causes that issue since it doesn't appear when I comment it.

**I actually have no clue how I could cleanup my subscription**

---

**Looks like the issue comes from the `useKeyboard()` Hook itself.** I made my own and it works like a charm:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

export default function useKeyboard() {
    const [shown, setShown] = useState(false);

    const handleKeyboardDidShow = () => {
        setShown(true);
    };
    const handleKeyboardDidHide = () => {
        setShown(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', handleKeyboardDidShow);
        Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', handleKeyboardDidHide);

        return () => {
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', handleKeyboardDidShow);
            Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', handleKeyboardDidHide);
        };
    }, []);

    return {
        isKeyboardShow: shown,
    };
}
```

Comment: You need to unmount keyboard at ```componentWillunmount```. See React hooks doc to how implement that: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi There is no such thing as `componentWillUnmount` in Hooks ; `useEffect()` is *like* a combination of `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: for example if you return a function from useEffect, it works as a componentWillUnmount

Comment: @pistou you can use `return () => cleanup()`. That is the way to clean up the effect as stated here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: The only thing I'd add to your latest solution is to suggest creating the listeners inside the `useEffect` callback; no reason for them to exist in a higher scope than that. In fact, because you pass an empty array to `useEffect`, the listeners will be ignored after the first render because the effect will only be invoked once.